# Log4j2 not logging statements from WAR and Non-EJB jars in an EAR

Tags: log4j2, ear, apache-commons-logging

I have an unpacked `EAR` deployed at `$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments` in `Wildfly-8.2.0.Final AS`. It contains unpacked `WAR` and application jar files.

```
HelloWorldEar-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear
-HelloWorldServlet-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
-lib
-META-INF
-aspectjrt-1.8.6.jar
-HelloWorldAnnotation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
-HelloWorldAspect-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
-HelloWorldCommonLib-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
-HelloWorldEJB-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
-log4j2.xml
```

`lib` folder of `EAR` contains log4j2 related APIs for providing logging feature.

```
lib
-commons-logging-1.2.jar
-HelloWorldLog4jPlugin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar (Jar containing custom log4j2 plugins)
-log4j-api-2.4.1.jar
-log4j-core-2.4.1.jar
-log4j-jcl-2.4.1.jar
-log4j-web-2.4.1.jar
```

I am initializing log4j2 configuration by initializing `log4j2.xml` using in a startup singleton bean in `HelloWorldEJB-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`.

```
String path = System.getProperty("jboss.home.dir")
                + "/standalone/deployments/HelloWorldEar-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear/log4j2.xml";
ConfigurationSource source;
        File configFile = new File(path);
        try {
            source = new ConfigurationSource(new FileInputStream(configFile), configFile);
            Configurator.initialize(null, source);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**log4j2.xml content**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="trace">
<Appenders>
<RollingFile name="SERVER_FILE" fileName="${sys:LOGS}/sample.log" filePattern="${sys:LOGS}/sample.log.%i" append="true">
<PatternLayout>
<pattern>%d %-5p [%c{1}] [EventId: %e] [%t] %m%n</pattern>
</PatternLayout>
<Policies>
<SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="500 KB" />
</Policies>
<DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5"/>
</RollingFile>
<Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
<PatternLayout>
<pattern>%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n</pattern>
</PatternLayout>
</Console>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
<Logger name="com.test.prototype.log4j" level="debug">
<AppenderRef ref="SERVER_FILE"/>
</Logger>
<Root level="debug" additivity="false">
<AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE"/>
</Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

All the sub-packages and classes are defined under the package `com.test.prototype.log4j`.

Log statements added in the classes of `HelloWorldEJB-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` gets logged in the log file.

**My issue is that 1. log statements from other application jars and WAR are not getting logged into the log file. 
2. Logging not working through commons-logging API though required system parameters for log4j2 is added.**

```
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log",
                "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger");
```

I have tried adding the `class-path` in the application jars and below listener in the `web.xml` of `WAR` file but nothing worked.
    
        org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContextListener

I need to have `log4j2.xml` under `EAR` and it should server for the all the application jars and WARs added in the EAR. Could anyone please help me about how to resolve this issue.

Comment: I am having the same issue and opened a service desk request https://issues.apache.org/jira/servicedesk/customer/portal/5/ATLAS-413

Comment: Many thanks for the comment.. Shailesh.

Comment: I could see the status is RESOLVED. Could you please add the link for the new JIRA ticket number raised in log4j2 queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried specifying the log4j2.xml config file location with system property `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=path/to/log4j2.xml`?
I suspect that the way you're initializing log4j now is not visible from other WARs.

If this fails, please raise this issue on the log4j2 Jira issue tracker. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2

Comment: Many thanks for the response.. Remko. I tried the system property log4j.configurationFile as a VM argument and also in java but log4j2.xml itself was not read and log files were not created. I also placed log4j2.xml in META-INF of EAR but not working. log4j2.xml is read and log files are generated when initializing log4j2 by coding using configuration as mentioned in the blog. log4j configuration is not visible to WARs and JARs in an unpacked EAR. Is this an issue ? If so, then I will raise the issue in log4j2 Jira issue tracker. Please confirm. Many thanks again and Happy Christmas!

Comment: Please do raise a log4j Jira issue for this with all the info you provided here (incl. your comment on how the system property doesn't seem to work). This is not expected behavior.

Comment: Many thanks for the confirmation.. Remko. I will do raise.

Comment: I did also add -Dlog4j.configurationFile=path/to/log4j2.xml, but is isn't working